# Cannot send emails to a gmail account through command line

Tags: bash, email, unix, command, ssmtp

I have edited ssmtp.conf file with all the details needed and configured ssmtp ! But when i enter

```
[root@localhost ssmtp]#    ssmtp user@gmail.com message
```

in terminal it prompts me with this error!!

```
[root@localhost ssmtp]#    bash: ssmtp: command not found error
```

Kindly help me out

(PS: Using Fedora 7 , commands similar to that of Centos)

Comment: You don't invoke the `ssmtp` daemon to send a message.  You are looking for the plain old `sendmail` command.  Not a programming question, anyway; voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I have not used ssmtp so far, but I guess it will be good if you look [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en).

Comment: Can anyone explain the reason for the answer downvote?

Comment: `ssmtp` is not installed in the `PATH` of regular users.  For example, on Debian, it is in `/usr/sbin/ssmtp`.  See my comment above as to why this isn't the command the OP is looking for in the first place anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> SSMTP is a program which delivers email from a local computer to a
>   configured mailhost (mailhub).[[1]](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP)

Assuming that you have already set up the ssmtp, first check if the `ssmtp` daemon is running using :

```
service ssmtp status
```

and then you may send mail using the `mail` command like

```
echo test | mail -v -s "testing ssmtp setup" user@gmail.com
```

If you have configured the ssmtp(with ssmtp.conf) with your `gmail` credentials, the above command will fist send the mail to the gmail hub and once the [authentication details](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en) are added it will be forwarded to **user@gmail.com** as if it was originally send from your actual mail account.

Comment: >>> MAIL From:<root@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=60 AUTH=root@localhost.localdomain
250 2.1.0 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<kartikdeshpande18@gmail.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <kartikdeshpande18@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 u474FXTQ011198 Message accepted for delivery
kartikdeshpande18@gmail.com... Sent (u474FXTQ011198 Message accepted
for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]

Comment: i am getting the following output !! but no mail delivered to the accounr